# Creating a Guid -> conversion from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, guid, act

I have the following code in VB.Net and I'm trying to convert it to C#.

```
 listContacts = ACT_FRAMEWORK.Contacts.GetContactsByID(Nothing, New Guid() {New Guid(ContactID)})
```

Below is my attempt so far:

```
 Guid[] test = new Guid[1];
 test[0] = Guid.NewGuid(ContactID);   
 contactList = actApp.Contacts.GetContactsByID(null, test);
```

The abover errors because NewGuid() takes no arguments. I have also tried.

```
test[0] = contactID1;
```

However, you can't convert from string to Guid. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Isn't there a [`Guid.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) you could use?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error so that could be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Guid.NewGuid` is a method, and you're not calling that method from your VB code - you're calling the *constructor* accepting a string. You can call that same constructor in C#:

```
// Using an array initializer for simplicity
Guid[] test = { new Guid(ContactID) };
```

Or if you want to make the call in one line as per your VB code:

```
contactList = actApp.Contacts.GetContactsByID(null, new[] { new Guid(ContactID) });
```

I think it's a shame that `NewGuid` has that name rather than `CreateGuid`, but such is life :(

Using `Guid.Parse` will work too of course - judging by the [.NET Core source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Guid.cs) they behave extremely similarly; the constructor just handles overflow exceptions slightly differently.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this! Must have made an error when attempting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Guid.Parse(ContactID.ToString());`

if ContactID is actually a string , simple write `Guid.Parse(ContactID);`